# Are methods with no return value more secure?

Tags: security, oop

Please excuse my naivety as I am not familiar with exploiting or eliminating software vulnerabilities, so I may be asking a question that doesn't make any sense. This is something I was thinking about recently and couldn't find anything online that specifically addressed my question.

Please compare the following classes (Java):

```
public class ProvidesCollection {
    private Item[] items;

    public Item[] getItemsArray() {
        return Arrays.copyOf(items, items.length);
    }
}

public class ContainsCollection {
    private Item[] items;

    public void actionItem(int itemNumber, ItemAction itemAction) {
        if(itemNumber < 0 || itemNumber > items.length)
            return; // Or handle as error

        Item i = items[itemNumber - 1];

        if(i != null)
            itemAction.performOn(i);
    }
}
```

The `ProvidesCollection` class is a typical OO design. The caller is trusted to loop through the items array returned from `getItemsArray`. If the caller forgets to do a bounds check it could open the code to a buffer overflow attack (if I'm not mistaken). I know Java's memory management avoids buffer overflows, so maybe Java is a bad example. Lets assume there is no mechanism for catching overflows.

The `ContainsCollection` class keeps the array completely hidden. Notice how the `actionItem` method allows the programmer to check for input errors and resolve them. Those responsible for implementing the API have more control over the data and flow of execution.

I would like to know, is the `ContainsCollection` class more secure than the `ProvidesCollection` class? Is there any evidence that avoiding return values (void methods) helps at all to remove a hacker's ability to exploit errors in the code?

Comment: From a functional programming perspective, functions with no return value are totally useless… And functions with side effects are more likely to introduce errors in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

No, `void` methods are not intrinsically more secure than methods that return values. You can write secure methods that return values, and you can write insecure methods that return nothing.

Typically, you will have `void` methods when you want to encapsulate some code that achieves a side-effect. For example, sending a file to a printer, changing the internal state of an object, or performing some other action. That should be the litmus test of whether or not the signature's return type should be `void` -- when it's a "fire and forget" type of operation.

Methods that return values are really only more insecure than void methods when they expose sensitive data to unscrupulous people. However that doesn't mean that the same unscrupulous people couldn't pass certain data into a void method's arguments to compromise security. Though void methods don't return values, they can still throw exceptions. A caller could possibly learn certain things about a void method's data by making it throw exceptions and try/catching them. Also, I have had the unfortunate opportunity to read code that logged passwords to trace files, and that logging method was `void`.

Say your `Item` object had properties like `CreditCardNumber` and `SocialSecurityNumber`. In this case, your first method may potentially expose a security vulnerability. However you could mitigate that by encrypting those values before returning the array reference (or do not even expose them at all). Any operations that need to operate with the credit card number to perform a side-effect action (such as authorizing a transaction) could be marked void, and do the decryption internally (or obtain the unencrypted value in an encapsulated operation).

But it's not necessarily the method's return signature that makes it more or less secure -- it's the data that is being exposed, and who it's being exposed to. Remember, anyone can write a silly `void` method that writes their database connection string to a public web page.

**Update**

> ...say a vulnerability exists because a method returns a bad value or
>   from bad usage of the return value. How can you fix the problem if
>   users depend on the returned value? There is no chance to go back and
>   remove the return because others depend on it.

If you need to, then you introduce a *breaking change*. This is a good reason to have clients depend on abstractions like interfaces rather than concrete types. Where you must have concrete types, design them carefully. Expose the minimum amount of information needed.

In the end, all data is just text. Your `Item` class will have string, integer, boolean, and other primitive values or nested objects that wrap primitives. You can still make changes to the encapsulated `getItemsArray` method to obfuscate sensitive data before returning the value if needed. If this has the potential to break client code, then you decide whether to bite the bullet and issue a breaking change or live with the flaw.

> Is the void method better because you can fix it?

No. Then, you would end up with an API that only performs actions, like a black hole where you send data and never hear from it again. Like I said before, a method should be `void` if it performs some side effect and the caller does not need to get anything back (except possibly catching exceptions). When your API needs to return data, return an abstraction like an interface rather than a concrete type.

Comment: Lets say you implement `actionItem` method from above and someone can send something to the method that "breaks it". You can fix all calls of `actionItem` by checking for the bad input. Then Lets say a vulnerability exists because a method returns a bad value or from bad usage of the return value. How can you fix the problem if users depend on the returned value? There is no chance to go back and remove the return because others depend on it. All users must be issued a warning about using the return value, or the method must be deprecated. Is the void method better because you can fix it?

Comment: Your example with credit card number and SSN brings up a good point. I will update my question soon to address that.